Using Mailgun.js within chrome extension
I am trying to use mailgun.js within my chrome extension. I am using the framework Plasmo to build my extension.
But for the moment, i am unable to use Mailgun.
Here is the code that i am using :
const formData = require("form-data");
const Mailgun = require("mailgun.js");
const mailgun = new Mailgun(formData);

And i have this error :
TypeError: define is not a function

Does someone had the same issue and find a solution ?

You can either build mailgun yourself and change amd to umd in the config or you can ask the author of mailgun to do it.
